# What is dynamic memory?

Tags: led-strip, ws2812b

I have an Arduino Uno and I'm trying to use it to provide data for 1200 WS2812B leds. When I tried to provide data for them, the Arduino IDE says "Sketch uses 5086 bytes (15%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1952 bytes (95%) of dynamic memory, leaving 96 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
Low memory available, stability problems may occur."

What does dynamic memory mean and how do I make more space for it. Also, I'm going to eventually switch the Arduino with a Raspberry Pi for wireless control of the leds. Will the Raspberry Pi have more dynamic memory?

Comment: Dynamic memory might simply mean RAM or registers in the processor. Yes, the Pi will have much more RAM.

Comment: It's unlikely that any modern system has dynamic memory, let alone only 2k of it. So I think this isn't a hardware question. That leaves a software one. There, it may go by the name of "heap memory." But again, it's hard to know why they'd only reserve out 2k and limit the heap space. So it's not that, either. This leaves me with internal static RAM as the limitation. And I have no idea why they call it "dynamic."

Comment: Does 1200 refer to the number of LEDs ? Are you controlling a thousand two hundred LEDs? Have you allocated any large array variables to store data for each LED ?

Comment: The ATmega238 is *extremely* RAM constrained relative to its more modern alternatives.  A pi has many orders of magnitude more memory, but is really a very different type of system not suited to the same tasks (for example it needs to be shut down properly before losing power.)  Likely what you want is a less constrained MCU, there are for example may ARM-based Arduino-ecosystem boards with at least five times as much RAM for a comparable or lesser price, and some with quite a bit more than that.

Comment: Yes, 1200 refers to the number of leds and I do have a large array to store data for each led.

Comment: @SENDHELP If the data sent to LEDS are repeating data like text, consider using a concept such as fonts or sprites to reduce the memory required to store that data. That way you may even be able to store the 'font' or 'sprites' in the  'program storage space' where 32256 bytes are available for storage.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using the FastLED library.

Comment: AJN what is repeating data?

Comment: This question on Arduino stackexchange may be helpful: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/221/what-can-i-do-if-i-run-out-of-flash-memory-or-sram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Global variables use 1952 bytes (95%) of dynamic memory, leaving 96 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes. Low memory available, stability problems may occur.

You have assigned 1952 bytes of RAM to global variables. Those are declared outside of function scopes, or inside function scopes with the `static` keyword.

The remaining 96 bytes is all you have for heap and stack (dynamic memory). Which is not much.

**Heap** is generally not used in embedded systems due to the lack of memory management to prevent memory fragmentation.

**Stack** however is **always** used.
When you call a function, the return address is put on stack, the arguments are put on stack, and all local variables of that function are put on the stack. Then you call the next function. And the next.
And an interrupt can be called anytime as well. Causing all processor (R0,R1..) registers to be put on stack to save the current state and prepare for execution of the interrupt service routine.

Stack is important. 96 bytes is not much. See if you can get more, or be really aware with what you are doing.

When you run out of stack, you have a big problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Of course you’re right on that point.

Answer (score 1):

One thing the OP has to consider...if the data for the 1200 LEDs is fixed in the program then the array of LED programming data should be declared as a **const** type (or other similar attribute for your embedded compiler) so that the array gets committed to the the FLASH area instead of the internal RAM area. From the details in the question it appears that you have lots of room left in the program FLASH space.

If the data for the LEDs is variable and gets downloaded to the MCU that controls the LED string then consider a protocol that downloads the LED image data in smaller blocks. You can then customize this protocol to a buffer size that you can comfortably accommodate within your RAM size on the microcontroller.

Lastly if the data for the LEDs is computed in real time by the microcontroller then you should consider making the compute algorithm able to be stopped temporarily when the RAM memory buffer gets full. Start the transmit sequence to the serial string of 1200 LEDs and then halt when reach the end of the buffer. Let the compute algorithm code run for the next increment of LED image and then let the transmit sequence resume for the next buffer content.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic memory likely refers to RAM or registers in the processor where data can be stored and manipulated.

To make space, you will have to reduce the number of variables that you are using.
In case, you have not made the 1952 bytes of global variables, they might have been made by the libraries that your program s using. Try to exclude some libraries and see if the number of global variables reduce.

The Raspberry Pi will have much more RAM than Arduino Uno.

Comment: The data for 1200 addressable LEDs would consume *at least* 1200 bytes.  The chip only has 2048..

Comment: @ChrisStratton - it depends upon how many bits are needed for each LED. If only one bit is need the entire bitmap could be packed into 150 bytes.

Comment: It seems that the particular LED OP is referring to is an RGB LED and can take 24 bits. I expected that they would have overshot the 2048 byte limit that way.

Comment: While one could write software to operate them with fewer, addressable LEDs tend to use 8 bits per channel.  In they are color there are three channels per lens.  The asker seems to have 1200 channels, I'd guess that is 400 RGB LEDs not 1200 monochrome ones but it hardly matters.  Code to use them in groups rather than all uniquely could help.  Ultimately the ATnega328 is the *wrong choice* as there's no sound reason to be so constrained.